# What is the correct way to cite forthcoming paper (without having infos)?

Tags: biblatex

I have to cite a forthcoming paper. I know this paper will be printed in 2014 in a collective book but I don't have any specific details about the publisher, collection, editors, ... Basically, I just have the title, the author, the date (2014) and an url to a preprint version.

What is the best way to cite such paper in an academic publication? I would like to use `@incollection` biblatex entry type but without the title of the book I obtained:

[image]

```
@InCollection{doe_articles_2014,
  Title                    = {article's title},
  Author                   = {Doe, John},
  Date                     = {2014},
  Url                      = {http://url_to_preprint_version.pdf}
}
```

Where do I place the "forthcoming" (or should I write "inpress"?)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That should be the value of the field `pubstate`, and descriptions of the different values are in section 4.9.2.11. Maybe `prepublished` suits best here, "the manuscript is published in a preliminary form or location, such as online version in advance of print publication"?

I wouldn't use `@incollection` if you don't know anything about that collection anyway, but

```
@article{doe_articles_2014,
  Title                    = {article's title},
  Author                   = {Doe, John},
  Date                     = {2014},
  Url                      = {http://url_to_preprint_version.pdf},
  pubstate                 = {prepublished}                  
}
```

Also, add `urldate`!